# Changing color of link dynamically in emberJS

Tags: javascript, ember.js, hyperlink, controller

This  is my app.hbs file, when i click the link it should be highlighted,Please help me how to do this.I am new to Ember and cannot find a clear solution to it. I am having ember version 2.18.

```
  {{#link-to 'adduser' id="addlink" }}MANUAL ADD {{/link-to}}</div>
  <br>
 {{#link-to 'csvadd' class="button"}}
  CSV ADD
  {{/link-to}}
```

Comment: Do you mean on mousedown the color should change? When you click on it, is the link in a subroute and is it still visible?

Comment: Yes the links will be in left side, the link specifice template will be loaded in center, so the clicked link should be highlighted, by changing the background colour of the link.

Comment: Did you check if the `active` class is usable here? The `link-to` helper should set the css class `active` on itself, if the links target route matches the current route. You can also change this with the `current-when` property (see [guides](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.18.0/templates/links/) and [docs](https://www.emberjs.com/api/ember/2.16/classes/Ember.Templates.helpers/methods/get?anchor=link-to)).

Comment: Do you want to highlight the current active link, or all that have been visited before?

Comment: current active link sir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create a component that can handle the state of clicked/active or not.
Your template can look something like this:

```
<span {{action "transitionToRoute"}}>
  <a>{{linkText}}</a>
</span>
```

Your js file looks like this:

```
import Component from '@ember/component';
import { inject as service } from '@ember/service';

export default Component.extend({
  router: service(),
  classNameBindings: ['highlighted'],
  highlighted: false.

  actions: {
    transitionToRoute() {
      this.set('highlighted', true);
      this.get('router').transitionTo(this.get('route'));
    }
  }
});
```

And, if you call your component hughlightedLink you would use it like this:

```
{{highlighted-link route="addUser" linkText="Add User"}}
```

Of course you would have to define the css highlighted class to style the span like you want to

Comment: Sir, since am new to ember, from where shall i call the component, i.e you have given as {{highlighted-link route="addUser"}}

Comment: In your template, where you wanted to put your {{link}} helper inside you now use the new component, ie your {{highlighted-link}} component. The component template (the span stuff) lives in its own file that was genereated by the ember cli when you created your new component

Comment: Sir, thank u for the help, i found the working, but this doesnot change my background color sir, i have simply specified the bg color for highlighted class in app.css, but no results.

Comment: Should I give this for each link, if i use the same for each link then what shall i give in the route when i call the component?, someone please help me!

Comment: You would have to use this component for each link that you want to highlight after it is clicked.
Do you have added the highlighted class in your css file? Also, please check this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48260028/changing-color-of-link-dynamically-in-emberjs/48261404?noredirect=1#comment83532370_48261404
So, you can understand what is going on.  
Also, if this answer is helping you, consider to mark it.

Comment: Yes sir i have added highlighted class in my css file, but in the template file it is specific for a given route, also what should i give in the template "{{actionName}}", I Have given my template like this-"                        
     <span  action="transitionToRoute" >
  <a href="#/adduser">Manual ADD</a>
</span>"   kindly help me, i am stuck!

Comment: Sorry, my ide interferred a little bit with my template. The span has to use the action helper,ie the {{action ... }} I have changed this in my  template above now.
Also I have updated the name of the variable you can give the component to display the route name. Please reread the original post. :-)

Comment: I have changed to above, but still couldnt get,where is component called here sir?

Comment: In what route do you want to show that? In all routes? Then put the component in your application.hbs file or the file where your navibation lives. (Which is as far as I understand your desire)

Comment: Do you still have problems with this or is it working?